# Center table when smaller than parent, scroll otherwise - without fixed width

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use CSS to achieve the following things on my page:

1. center table when the table is smaller (less wide) than the parent 
   container.
2. make sure a scrollbar is visible when the table is wider than the parent container. In this case the table should begin right at the left edge of the parent container (i.e. no extra space).

And I'd like to avoid using any fixed width to do this (I'd like this to be a somewhat reusable component).

I can use `display: block;` to make the table scrollable, but then it fails the first requirement.

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

set max-width or max-height  property  for the child table and set overflow:auto to enable scroll bar if width is greater than the child. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what would be the `max-width` value for the child?

Comment: add max-width and max-height  as 200px; to see if you are getting the scroll bar. Then set the width as per your use

Comment: I see -- however I'd like to do this without setting any fixed dimensions (see the original post).

Answer (score 0):

put the table inside div with *display:inline block; max-width:100%;*
and for the table *display:block; overflow:auto;*

for example:

```
   <div class="table-container">
      <table class="my-table"> ... </table>
   </div>
```

the styles is:

```
   <style>
       body{
       text-align: center;
       }
       .table-container{
       display:inline block; 
       max-width:100%;
       }
       .my-table{
       display:block; 
       overflow:auto;
       }
   </style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. The table wasn't scrollable.